# How to change default paper size in 'Print to file'?

Tags: printing

Whenever I hit my `Print to file`:

[image]

Default paper size seems to be `US Letter`:

[image]

Is there a way to set different default (A4 for instance) here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure but try this and reboot your computer:

```
paperconfig -p a4
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/paperconfig.8.html

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and got console output of set parameter. Unfortunately - it didn't change the default.

Comment: If you want to set it A4,Add the following lines into /etc/environment file:
`LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8" `

Try `sudo paperconfig -p a4` restart your computer and let us know the result.

Comment: I've changed it in `/etc/default/locale` (does it make a difference?) and it solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I am not expert on localization in Ubuntu :) But i think no difference.However, also you can reach your achieve with this command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libpaper1`

Comment: @Hckr `dpkg-reconfigure` did **not** change the paper size for me on Ubuntu 12.04. including restarting.

Comment: @radek Be careful! Appending `LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8` to `/etc/default/locale` caused that my Ubuntu 12.04. would **no longer boot**! Please be precise about the settings you suggest, if I have mistaken your comment.

Comment: @Hckr The only settings that worked for me is adding `LANG` and `LC_PAPER` to `/etc/environment`. Thanks! As a follow up please consider reading [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142253/more-print-to-file-settings), too.

Comment: I am using Debian with Gnome 3.30.2 and this answer got me in the right direction. This might help newer Ubuntu Users as well: In my case it was `sudo paperconf -p a4` which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way

Click on `Paper size`, select `manage custom paper` and give your custom paper size here